# The person operating a piece of software

Tags: single-word-requests

For a piece of software, I am in need of a term, but being non-native English speaker, I find it hard:

In the software, a person is represented as "a member (of a community)". One such member drives, or operates the software and causes (triggers) events. Those events now need a reference to "the member that triggered the event".

What would that person or member be called?

The most descriptive terms that I come up with are all clumsy, seem to miss the point, or are "in use" already:

- "current member" - What is current? When is current?
- "operating member" - Operating gives me the idea of a surgeon operating a patient, or a driver operating a car, but not a person clicking around in a piece of software. Is that just me?
- Triggerer - is that even a word?
- "user" - Common in software, but this term is already taken due to external constraints: a user means something different already.

To clarify the last: When I am "using a website" or "using an app" (or web application), I am "the user". But from the point of view of that web application, there are many users. E.g. Stackexchange (SE) has millions of users. So, when John "upvotes" something on SE, what is that particular user called? The "upvoter" is most specific, in this example. But would there be a more generic term for "the person causing the upvote to happen"?

Since it is used in software to name methods and classes, it is hard to give a sentence, but I'll try. I'm looking for the generic term that can replace all the specific names.

The form is "The [actor] that [caused this action], was the ... ([specific name]).

- The person that made this specific edit, was the ... (editor)
- The members that invited another member, was the ... (inviter)
- The admin that locked this thread, was the ... (moderator)
- The user that asked this question, was the ... (inquisitor)

I'd prefer a single concise term and not something combined like "acting member" if avoidable.

Comment: 'Operator' has the prototypical sense 'one (or something) that operates [something]', but has perhaps confusing specifying definitions.

Comment: I think that *operate" is the wrong verb. The usual collocation is "to use" software.

Comment: You're criteria are unclear, but "user" would seem to be the closest fit.

Comment: @HotLicks In order to clarify the criteria: could you explain what is unclear?

Comment: @Greybeard. You are correct (and this is where the term user is used for). I'm looking at it from the point of the software. This software has many users: but what is the "person operating this particular thread" called?

Comment: I agree the criteria are unclear. "User" itself is commonly used in this way. A user is the person interacting with the application's front-end in such ways that invoke implementations of the application. Even in the context of a specific user invoking a specific implementation, the user is still a user.

Comment: What sentence would you use this word in? The answers will vary depending on this. (Eg I would not use “*operator* of the upvote” if that was the context.)

Comment: @Laurel: good one, I think that would clarify it. I've added some sentences.

Comment: If one member of the community triggers the events what do the other members do?

Comment: @BoldBen The other members don't necessarily do anything. This is seen from the POV of the software. Events are not exposed to the public, they are internal. The effects such events have, are exposed. E.g. a InvitedMember event will cause an email to be sent. But that InvitedMember-event has a `inviter` which is a ...(more generic term) ?

Answer (score 2):

We have two words for this.

> Operator
> 1: one that operates: such as
>   a: one that operates a machine or device
>
> [operator - merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operator)

This is the formal of the two. Often used in government documents.

> End-User
> the ultimate consumer of a finished product
> [end user - merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end%20user)

This is more often used in documents produced by private software development companies.

> In product development, an end user (sometimes end-user) is a person who ultimately uses or is intended to ultimately use a product. The end user stands in contrast to users who support or maintain the product, such as sysops, system administrators, database administrators, information technology experts, software professionals and computer technicians.
>
> [end user - wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_user)

Neither word is exclusive to software.

There are many roles to play when working with software. Users who play those roles are often named after the role; e.g., user who administrates: administrator.

Comment: The elaboration given is slightly incorrect. End users are contrasted against admins of various sorts (configuration admin users, database admin users, network admins, etc.), but most of these various roles are inclusive to the broader group "users". Any customer that uses any component of the software in any way is a user, while end users, config users, and so on are all just specific kinds of users.

Answer (score -1):

> "the member that triggered the event"

**instigator**

> The instigator of an event is the person who causes it to happen.
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/instigator

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: In my opinion, downvotes without an explanation are not valid!

Comment: Being technically correct is a poor substitute for following usage.

Comment: @candied_orange - The way the question is phrased, it seems to be asking for something that is non-standard. For example the OP suggests "triggerer".

Comment: It looks line a perfectly valid suggestion to me, the only change I would make would be to refer to the person triggering the event as the "instigating member of the community" and the others, possibly, as the "reacting members of the community".